# How to count array elements properly with multiple aggregation in Spring Data MongoDB?

Tags: java, mongodb, aggregation-framework, spring-data-mongodb

I need to create advanced aggregation using Spring Data MongoDB having model like that:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Document
public class City {

  @Id
  @JsonSerialize(using = ToStringSerializer.class)
  private ObjectId id;

  private Address description;

  private String name;

  ...

}

@Getter
@Setter
@Document
public class Library {

  @Id
  @JsonSerialize(using = ToStringSerializer.class)
  private ObjectId id;

  private Address address;

  private String workingHours;

  @JsonSerialize(using = ToStringSerializer.class)
  private ObjectId cityId;

  ...

}

@Getter
@Setter
@Document
public class Book {

  @Id
  @JsonSerialize(using = ToStringSerializer.class)
  private ObjectId id;

  private Boolean published;

  private Boolean hidden;

  private String title;

  @JsonSerialize(using = ToStringSerializer.class)
  private ObjectId libraryId;

  ...

}
```

pom.xml

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Cities collection:

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5f47878c95f47e209402fe15"), 
    "name" : "Warsaw",
    "description" : "Sample description"
}
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5f4787918b343fff4f52c270"), 
    "name" : "Chicago",
    "description" : "Sample description"
}
```

Libraries collection:

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5f45440ee89590218e83a697"), 
    "workingHours" : "8:00 PM - 8:00 AM",
    "address" : DBRef("addresses", ObjectId("5f4544198da452a5523e3d11")),
    "cityId": ObjectId("5f47878c95f47e209402fe15")
},
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5f478725d1507323a80efa31"), 
    "workingHours" : "8:00 PM - 8:00 AM",
    "address" : DBRef("addresses", ObjectId("5f4787379e72f882e4d26912")),
    "cityId": ObjectId("5f47878c95f47e209402fe15")
},
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5f47872f7c4872d4983961f5"), 
    "workingHours" : "8:00 PM - 8:00 AM",
    "address" : DBRef("addresses", ObjectId("5f47873d5ddedadb3d6ddd6e")),
    "cityId": ObjectId("5f4787918b343fff4f52c270")
}
```

Books collection:

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5f454423be823729015661ed"), 
    "published": true,
    "hidden": false,
    "title": "The Hobbit, or There and Back Again"
    "libraryId": ObjectId("5f45440ee89590218e83a697")
},
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5f45445b876d08649b88ed5a"), 
    "published": true,
    "hidden": false,
    "title": "Harry Potter and the Philosopher's Stone"
    "libraryId": ObjectId("5f45440ee89590218e83a697")
},
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5f45446c7e33ca70363f629a"), 
    "published": true,
    "hidden": false,
    "title": "Harry Potter and the Cursed Child"
    "libraryId": ObjectId("5f45440ee89590218e83a697")
},
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5f45447285f9b3e4cb8739ad"), 
    "published": true,
    "hidden": false,
    "title": "Fantastic Beasts and Where to Find Them"
    "libraryId": ObjectId("5f45440ee89590218e83a697")
},
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5f45449fc121a20afa4fbb96"), 
    "published": false,
    "hidden": false,
    "title": "Universal Parks & Resorts"
    "libraryId": ObjectId("5f45440ee89590218e83a697")
},
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5f4544a5f13839bbe89edb23"), 
    "published": false,
    "hidden": true,
    "title": "Ministry of Dawn"
    "libraryId": ObjectId("5f45440ee89590218e83a697")
}
```

Depending on the context of the user, I have to return cities with count of libraries and books in the city that can be filtered based on `startsWith()` or `like()` principle.

Assuming that I have 2 libraries in one city and 1 library in the other.

1. I need to count libraries using lookup first and return `librariesCount` - it will be `2` and `1`.
2. I need to fetch / lookup books in every library, then count them as 'booksCount' and then multiply by `librariesCount` to get total amount of `booksCount` in the city (let's call it `cityBooksCount`).

I came up with aggregation like this:

```
Criteria criteria = Criteria.where("_id");

MatchOperation matchOperation = Aggregation.match(criteria);
            
LookupOperation lookupOperation = LookupOperation.newLookup().from("libraries").localField("_id").foreignField("cityId").as("libraries");

UnwindOperation unwindOperation = Aggregation.unwind("libraries", true);

LookupOperation secondLookupOperation = LookupOperation.newLookup().
              from("books").
              localField("libraryIdArray").
              foreignField("libraryId").
              as("books");

UnwindOperation secondUnwindOperation = Aggregation.unwind("books", true);

AggregationOperation group = Aggregation.group("_id")
            .first("_id").as("id")
            .first("name").as("name")
            .first("description").as("description")
            .push("libraries").as("libraries")
            .push("books").as("books");

ProjectionOperation projectionOperation = Aggregation.project("id", "description", "name")              
.and(VariableOperators.mapItemsOf(ConditionalOperators.ifNull("libraries").then(Collections.emptyList()))
.as("library").andApply(aggregationOperationContext -> {
                  Document document = new Document();
                  document.append("id", "$$library._id");
                  return document;
              })).as("libraryIdArray")
.and(ConvertOperators.valueOf(ArrayOperators.Size.lengthOfArray(ConditionalOperators.ifNull("libraries").then(Collections.emptyList()))).convertToString()).as("librariesCount")        
.and(ConvertOperators.valueOf(ArrayOperators.Size.lengthOfArray(ConditionalOperators.ifNull("books").then(Collections.emptyList()))).convertToString()).as("cityBooksCount");

Aggregation aggregation = Aggregation.newAggregation(matchOperation, lookupOperation, unwindOperation, secondLookupOperation, secondUnwindOperation, group, projectionOperation);
            
mongoTemplate.aggregate(aggregation, "cities", Document.class).getRawResults().get("results");
```

Thanks to the help of one of the stackoverflow users I was able to obtain `librariesCount` in proper way. Unfortunately `cityBooksCount` always point to `0`.

I'm not so familiar with MongoDB, but I know that `$lookup` [operation is possible on array](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#use-lookup-with-an-array), so I've tried mapping libraries array to list of `ObjectId`, but it's not working properly. Probably I'm doing something wrong, but I don't know where is the problem. I get the proper amount of cities with other projected fields.

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong and how to correct it?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: you don't have `libraryIdArray`, how do you select it as localField?

Comment: may I know what you try to achieve?

Comment: @varman I make `libraryIdArray` in `projectionOperation` based on collection. Generally speaking first lookup is fetching libraries based on cities. I want the second lookup to fetch books based on libraries.

Comment: in the second lookup you mentioned `libraryIdArray`, where does it come from?

Comment: @varman I made it in the `projectionOperation` down below. Maybe I understand something differently and I can't create it like this.

Comment: You have given` projectionOperation ` at last inside the `Aggregation.newAggregation()`, This works one after other, so thats wrong. Means `projectionOperation ` stage executes at last

Comment: That's fine, I appreciate that you tried something. What is your final output you try to achive?

Comment: @varman I have to calculate how many libraries there are in each city. Then I need to calculate how many books there are in each city. Then I need to return all cities with their `librariesCount` and `booksCount`.

Comment: Does https://mongoplayground.net/p/HKYmDcjGQZb help you?

Comment: @varman Yes, seems to be working properly with Spring Data aggregations. I have to check it in other scenarios, but that's probably the solution. Thank you very much. :) Should I answer this question with my implementation or no?

Comment: Ye, no problem! :)

Comment: If you feel trouble in making aggregation in spring, let me know, i can help you, but please try to do your own which helps to to improve the knowledge

Comment: Okay, how can I contact you instead of making whole new posts on stackoverflow?

Comment: Haha, may be social media? But better to post here, other developers may give you more efficient than me asap

Comment: @varman I have one more problem. I want to match only active libraries in the cities (to count them) and return ALL CITIES with those matched libraries. I'm using `MatchOperation secondMatchOperation = Aggregation.match(Criteria.where("libraries.active"))`. I'm calling it after first lookup, so it should work properly (for another query with only books lookup it is working properly). It returned matched libraries properly, but also returned only those cities, where libraries were matched. Do you understand? I don't know how to briefly present this problem.

Comment: @varman I've also checked it more carefully and your playground doesn't work exactly as it should. First result returns `libraryCount` as 7, but in the collection we have only 3 libraries (?), that could be fetched by lookup. It should have returned 2. Second result gives 1 as proper amount. I'm not sure what's wrong here, it should work properly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220581/discussion-between-mattit-and-varman).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be giving you the expected answer.

```
db.cities.aggregate([
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "Libraries",
      "localField": "_id",
      "foreignField": "cityId",
      "as": "libraries"
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: {
      path: "$libraries",
      preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true
    }
  },
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "Books",
      "localField": "libraries._id",
      "foreignField": "libraryId",
      "as": "books"
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: {
      path: "$books",
      preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id",
      name: {
        $first: "$name"
      },
      description: {
        $first: "$description"
      },
      libraries: {
        $push: "$libraries"
      },
      books: {
        $push: "$books"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 1,
      name: 1,
      description: 1,
      libraryCount: {
        $size: "$libraries"
      },
      bookCount: {
        $size: "$books"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

As we discussed, there are some slight changes. Hope, you understood how to convert the mongo query to spring data aggregation.